# Does the apostrophe come before or after the s when the noun is less than one?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

I have a noun, "second", that I need to make possessive in the sentence,

> It's like having a second's slower reflexes.

When I make it plural, the apostrophe comes after the *s*.

> It's like having two seconds' slower reflexes.

However, my noun is actually a quarter second.  You only use the singular noun when there is *exactly* one of it, so you use the plural for zero and fragments of the noun.

> They finished the task with zero seconds remaining.
>
> They finished the task with .25 seconds remaining.

Since the noun in my sentence is plural, does that mean that for the possessive the apostrophe comes after the *s*, or since it is not more than one, does it come before the *s*?  (My intuition says it comes after.)

> It's like having a quarter second*s'* slower reflexes.
>
> It's like having a quarter second*'s* slower reflexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possessive apostrophe comes before the *s*. If you look at your sentence:

> It's like having a quarter second['s or s'] slower reflexes.

There is a give away that you're actually talking about a singular thing, and not a plural. That is, you write "**a** quarter second". If you were writing "0.25 seconds" that would be different, but "a quarter second" is singular. It's not a "second", it's a "quarter second", which I would guess has come about through deletion of "of a" between *quarter* and *second* and gradually been normalised.

So the correct placement of the apostrophe is before the s:

> It's like having a quarter second's slower reflexes.

---

Note:

You also have the option to not use the possessive at all and treat "a quarter second" as a noun adjunct:

> It's like having a quarter second slower reflexes.